# Unordered List height 100% not fitting to height of parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an unordered list inside of a div (using the bootstrap panel). The div is set to 100% height, and without the unordered list inside of it, fill up the rest of the browser window as desired. When I add the unordered list, instead of the unordered list filling in the parent div and using the "overflow-y: scroll" correctly, it flows off the page with all of its content.

I want the unordered list to snap to the height of its parent div so that all of my content stays on the browser window so that the user only has to scroll inside of the unordered list's parent div.

How do I make the unordered list's height snap to its parent div completely?

```
<div class="panel panel-default classroomPanel">
    <div class="panel-heading">Choose Your Classroom</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="classroomList">
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my CSS as follows:

```
.classroomPanel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px; 
}

.classroomPanel div.panel-body {
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

ul.classroomList {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y:scroll; 
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
 }
```

Comment: ul is standard an inline-block. If you want to give it a specific height make it a block. 

ul.classroomList {
    display:block;
}

that should do it

Comment: Adding "display: block" did not work.

Comment: Another problem is that its inside a div without a specific height. I dont think it will take the 100% since it doesnt know what the 100% is. Test it by giving the div.panel-body a height of for example 400px;

Comment: Setting the div.panel-body height to 400px made the unordered list's height fit to that 400px. Is there any way to make the panel-body still fit to 100% of the browser window's height and make the unordered list know what that is?

Comment: i am afraid not. height:100%; usually (most browsers) only works if its parent has an exact height. In this case the height of the panel-body is depended of the height of the panel-header.

You still might try this
.classroomPanel div.panel-body:after ul.classroomList { height: 100%; }

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks for your help. I'll just have to give the parent div a fixed height.

Comment: Your welcome and goodluck

Comment: I don't think you want the `ul` to be 100% height. You want the container that the `ul` is in to be 100% height, then the `ul` will trigger the container's overflow if there's more list items.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing this?

```
ul {
   list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Just be careful for different browsers; it may not work perfectly for each.

Comment: I tried your solution, and it unfortunately did did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It happens normally when child Divs width or height is greater than the parent Div. What you  are doing is that you are using `over-flow:scroll`for the child Div's.The `li`s total height will be more than the height of the container.
But it is also possible that the `li`s total height is more than the parent container Div(panel panel-default classroomPanel). So it flows off the page. The exact problem could be solved by inspecting element of all the Divs. 
You can try

```
<div class="panel panel-default classroomPanel" style="overflow-y:hidden">
    <div class="panel-heading">Choose Your Classroom</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="classroomList">
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
            <li>sample element</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```